# Single Line to Double-line Formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

In my job I have to enter warranty information so that POs can be cut. Vendors are very particular with how this is entered and each one has their own format.

One of them requires data be entered:

> SN:
> MACHTYPE:

Further, the information for this is sent in a single composite number, something like:

> 10Y754235FUYJ9

Requiring the final input of data to be:

> SN:10Y75423
> MACHTYPE:UYJ9

The first 4 digits of the composite are the MACHTYPE and the final 8 are the Serial Number.

The impasse I've reached is I can't seem to get auto-fill to replicate the skipping of lines as I've formatted. It will jump a number of lines equal to however many I've selected.

[image]

Any ideas about getting it to replicate the first four Formatted Data? I've been throwing myself at this for a couple hours now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are trying to do. Can you please explain?

Comment: If what you are trying to achieve is formatting so that different rows are displayed with different formats in a cyclical way, a standard trick is to use conditional formatting with a condition formula that involves modular arithmetic and the function `ROW()`. Instead of trying to get different formatting in different rows -- use the same formatting in *all* rows, but with conditions that cause the formatting to be active in *some* rows.

Comment: You can also insert two lines per cell in column `F`, separated by `vbLf`, then enable automatic height and wrapping. I think you should post an image of the *desired* output to clarify the problem.

Comment: I wonder what you mean by "auto-fill". To add formatting to new rows at the bottom of the sheet you should select 2 entire rows which are formatted the way you want and "Paint" their format to any number of rows at the bottom. If you select 8 or 9 rows you will have 4 pairs of rows formatted like the original. To copy formulas repeat the same process using copy/paste. If you know VBA, automate the process for greater ease and more precision.

Comment: What is the relationship between your question and its title?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over complicating it by using two rows for the *Formatted Data*.  I'd wrap the text (Home tab > Alignment section) for the cells in column `F` and use the following formula to insert a new line:

```
=CONCATENATE("SN:",B1,CHAR(10),"MATCHTYPE:",C1)
```

Then just leave the formatting like you had it by row...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's focus on the title. When `A1` is `10Y754235FUYJ9`,

```
="SN:"&LEFT(A1,8)&CHAR(10)&"MATCHTYPE:"&RIGHT(A1,4)
```

will give you the output:

```
SN:10Y75423
MATCHTYPE:UYJ9
```

And don't forget to set the `wrap text` checked at `Format Cells` menu.